# Error Handling - Runtime Error Box Still Occurring

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I'm trying to implement an error handler into my code, I've managed to create a message box if a run time error occurs but after clearing the message box the run time error box pops up. This is a snippet of my code:

```
combinedFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

If combinedFilename <> "False" Then

    Set combinedWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(combinedFilename)

Else

    MsgBox "No file was uploaded", vbExclamation


End If
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: There's no error handling in your snippet.  Do you have any `On Error` statements?  A typical example would be `On Error GoTo Err`, then an `Err:` block to handle the error itself.

Comment: I don't see any error handling code?

Comment: This is likely not the problem here, but it's worth checking in the VB Editor >> `Tools >> Options >> General tab >> Error Trapping` make sure it's not set to "Break on all errors"

Answer (score 0):

Write `Err.Clear` after the `MsgBox`.

If clears the Error. See this small sample:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print 5 / 0           '11, because this is the number of the error.
    Debug.Print Err.Number
    Err.Clear
    Debug.Print Err.Number      '0, because the error is cleared.

End Sub
```